# Bluetooth SPP device on Windows 8

Tags: bluetooth, microsoft-metro, spp

I've been banging my head against the proverbial wall trying to working out how to talk to a Bluetooth device that uses the Serial Port Profile (SPP) in a Windows 8 Metro-Style App.  I'm starting to come to the conclusion that it's not currently possible, but was wondering if anyone else has been able to get this to work, or can think of anything to try.

There doesn't seem to be an API available to do this, but would it be possible to connect to a device at a lower level?

Comment: That's my conclusion too... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a Microsoft rep, this is not possible in Metro:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tailoringappsfordevices/thread/0cb2a6c1-d1f1-4872-aa32-709acd90b94d

It should be possible to write a custom driver to accomplish this, but that is significantly more of a challenge than writing a Metro app.